# Why is this version of 'fix' more efficient in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, fixpoint-combinators

In Haskell, this is a simple (naive) definition of a fixed point

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = f (fix f)
```

But, here is how Haskell actually implements it (more efficient)

```
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

My question is why is the second one more efficient than the first?

Comment: on what base do you claim one is more efficient than the other - can you provide some evidence

Comment: Well, for one, it seems to run faster. And also, see here http://h2.jaguarpaw.co.uk/posts/polymorphic-recursion-combinator/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The slow `fix` calls `f` on each step of recursion, while the fast one calls `f` exactly once. It can be visualized with tracing:

```
import Debug.Trace

fix  f = f (fix f)
fix' f = let x = f x in x

facf :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
facf f 0 = 1
facf f n = n * f (n - 1)

tracedFacf x = trace "called" facf x

fac  = fix tracedFacf
fac' = fix' tracedFacf
```

Now try some running:

```
> fac 3
called
called
called
called
6
> fac' 3
called
6
```

In more detail, `let x = f x in x` results in a lazy thunk being allocated for `x`, and a pointer to this thunk is passed to `f`. On first evaluating `fix' f`, the thunk is evaluated and all references to it (here specifically: the one we pass to `f`) are redirected to the resulting value. It just happens that `x` is given a value that also contains a reference to `x`.

I admit this can be rather mind-bending. It's something that one should get used to when working with laziness.

Comment: I guess I'm somewhat unable to parse english today but if you say "calls f exactly once" you are not talking about evaluating `f` for some point right? because obviously you'll have to call `facf` a couple of times no matter what magic is involved (moving the `trace` into `facf` will show it)

Comment: `facf` isn't recursive, we call it once, and `fix'` returns a function object. When we call *that* function object with a numeric argument, it calls itself  recursively possibly multiple times (which can be again traced as you say).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a more general question. Can all recursive functions be 'optimized' by using this `let` binding approach? If so, why doesn't GHC internally use this technique to optimize recursions? I would assume the _naive_ way of writing recursive functions is easier to read and understand.

Comment: @VijayaRani simple recursive definitions are already about as fast and optimizable as they can be. It's just the slow `fix` definition that introduces overhead compared to simple recursive definitions.

Comment: Is this something that is actually guaranteed by the language specification or does it rely on private internal implementation details of one particular version of one particular implementation?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think this always (or necessarily ever) helps when you're calling `fix` with a function that takes two arguments to produce a function taking one argument. You'd have to run some benchmarks to see. But you can also call it with a function taking one argument!

```
fix (1 :)
```

is a *circular linked list*. Using the naive definition of `fix`, it would instead be an infinite list, with new pieces built lazily as the structure is forced.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this has been asked already, but I couldn't find the answer. The reason is that the first version

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

is a recursive function, so it can't be inlined and then optimized. From the [GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#inline-noinline-pragma):

> For example, for a self-recursive function, the loop breaker can only be the function itself, so an `INLINE` pragma is always ignored.

But

```
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

isn't recursive, the recursion is moved into the `let` binding, so it's possible to inline it.

**Update:** I did some tests and while the former version doesn't inline while the latter does, it doesn't seem to be crucial for performance. So the other explanations (a single object on heap vs creating one every iteration) seem to be more accurate.

Comment: I don't think there is any inlining involved.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Correct. Both variants of `fix` get compiled in a different way, one via a `let rec` binding, the other via `rec`. (`-ddump-simpl`).